# Regex for matching words, even though they might be words apart

Tags: php, regex

So for the string:

```
A large chicken, either thighs or breasts
```

I need a regex to match the term "`chicken breast`"

So it would be something like `/chicken(.*?)breast/` would it not?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this before asking?

Comment: yeah and it doesnt work, infact Im doing two matches for plurals, so the regex Ive got at the mo is /chicken(.*?)breasts|chicken(.*?)breastss/i

Comment: The regex in your question seems to work, the one in your comment as well, except that the second part of your regex (`chicken(.*?)breastss`) will never be matched, so it's kind of pointless adding it.
(you will always match "chicken, either thighs or breasts").

Turning the or around would work though. `chicken(.*?)breastss|chicken(.*?)breasts`

Comment: Would the `chicken` and `breast` be on different lines? The dot metacharacter, by default, does not match newline characters which *might* be why you're not seeing a match.

Comment: I found the correct regex would be `chicken(.*?)breasts?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Something like that.